# How to create Namespace On HBase

Tags: linux, networking, hadoop, hbase

I have installed HBase on Linux platform Manually and with Cloudera. I can able to create tables on it, but i when am creating a namespace it trowing one error like this on both installations.

```
hbase(main):004:0> create_namespace 'my_ns'
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_namespace' for #<Object:0x699dbc28>
```

Hbase Version 0.94.12 Please help me on this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

namespaces isn't available in 0.94 I believe.

The major effort on namespaces isn't completed yet.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8015

However, it seems like some of it has been committed back. Most of the tickets say that it is fixed against 0.95.2 and 0.98.

Comment: Thanks... Am going to try that

Comment: @KiranHaridas It was a while ago but I think this answer deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To create a namespace in HBase versions 0.96 and greater

1.Open HBase shell from HBase bin using command:

```
./hbase shell
```

2.Execute HBase shell command `create_namespace 'testa'`

```
hbase(main):006:0> create_namespace 'testa'
Took 0.2373 seconds
```

Note: namespace is not available in HBase versions < 9.96

Answer (score 0):

As Donald mentioned Namespaces are not a feature of HBase 0.94. They were added in v0.96 (see 0.96 announcement [here](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hbase_0_96_0_released)). (0.95 was a development version not a released version)