# Namespace creation on HBASE

Tags: hbase

I am trying to create namespace but I am getting an error something like the one given below

```
hbase(main):031:0> create namespace 'Aniruddha'                                                                                       
NoMethodError: undefined method `namespace' for #<Object:0xf28473>
```

I am using hbase 0.96.2

```
hbase(main):032:0> version
0.96.2-hadoop2, r1581096, Mon Mar 24 16:03:18 PDT 2014<br/>
```

Same question had been asked 
in the link

[How to create Namespace On HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430739/how-to-create-namespace-on-hbase)

Yet I am not able to figure out what is the way out!! Or just explain to me what to do in this case
Please help

---

Thankyou

Comment: you are just missing an underscore. the command is "create_namespace"

Comment: Yeah!! finally I got it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mistake in you command statement, create namespace should be written with _ not a space. Correct command should be look like this

```
hbase(main):003:0> create_namespace 'test'
0 row(s) in 0.1650 seconds

hbase(main):004:0> list_namespace
NAMESPACE                                                                                                                                                                  
default                                                                                                                                                                    
hbase                                                                                                                                                                      
test                                                                                                                                                                       
4 row(s) in 0.0100 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexander :)